# Informatica permission and account to write target file to another server folder

Tags: informatica

I need to specify that target file to be written to a specified folder in another server beside on the same box as Informatica.

I looked in the session property and do not see an entry to specify the account name and password?

The account name has the permission to the folder in the other server.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a ftp connection string if you want to directly write to a file in another server.

Or else you can write a script which would ftp the file after it is generated on the informatica server.

Answer (score 1):

Beside using FTP it might be possible (depending on your environment) to map the required server path and use it directly.